# Whose name is written on the twelfth foundation stone? Is it Judas Iscariot Or Matthias or Paul?

Tags: revelation, apostle

Revelation 21:14 says:

> And the wall of the city had twelve foundation stones, and on them were the twelve names of the twelve apostles of the Lamb. (NASB)

We pretty much know what the names of eleven of them are, but who's name is written on the 12th? Is it Judas Iscariot Or Matthias or Paul(as some claim)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matthias' name is the twelfth name on the foundations. He was numbered among the twelve apostles and took Judas' role in oversight (as treasurer):

> Act 1:17  For **he was numbered with us**, and had obtained part of this
>   ministry.
>
> Act 1:20  For it is written in the book of Psalms, Let his habitation
>   be desolate, and let no man dwell therein: and his bishoprick let
>   another take.
>
> Act 1:26  And they gave forth their lots; and the lot fell upon
>   Matthias; **and he was numbered with the eleven apostles.**

While Paul claimed to have received apostleship that was not inferior to the "Wordy Dozen" he was never numbered among them.

Joseph aka Barsabas will forever be the "fifth Beatle":

> Act 1:23  And they appointed two, Joseph called Barsabas, who was
>   surnamed Justus, and Matthias.  Act 1:24  And they prayed, and said,
>   Thou, Lord, which knowest the hearts of all men, shew whether of these
>   two thou hast chosen,  Act 1:25  That he may take part of this
>   ministry and apostleship, from which Judas by transgression fell, that
>   he might go to his own place.  Act 1:26  And they gave forth their
>   lots; and the lot fell upon Matthias; and he was numbered with the
>   eleven apostles.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is a bit different: the "twelve" were followers of Jesus *before his death and revelation*.  At that point Saul was the antithesis of such a person, and continued in fire and persecution for quite some time.  He himself considered himself by the Roman name he adopted for himself, and would be among the last to lay claim to being 'one of the twelve' -- lest any man should boast.

Yes, his contributions to the strength and form of Christianity are tremendous and strong, but he was not one of those Jesus picked to follow Him -- nor, if you remember, did Jesus call him to be so on the road to Damascus.  What he did was of free will, resolve, and commitment, not so much as a 'disciple'.

Comment: - R.M. **A.)** This would be improved by citing Acts 1:21 to support: "beginning with the baptism of John ", (Acts 1:21); But the rest seems unsupportable by the texts: **B.)** The disciples actually did have free will - many falling away, (John 6:66);  But, the text suggests Paul's decision *was not at all* "free will" - literally extorted to pursue Christianity or remain blind, (Acts 9); Perhaps later it was; **C.)** Paul's apostleship to the Gentiles was rejected by some, but not others, (1 Cor 9:2). But, his ministry was affirmed by Peter,  (2 Pet. 3:15), and the other Apostles, (Acts 15);

Answer (score 0):

Like other times in Peter's life, he stepped out in front of God in saying "Let's see which of these two God has chosen." In reality God had chosen neither Joseph or Matthias, but Saul. In 1 Cor. 9:1 and throughout 2 Cor. Paul identifies himself with the 12 by saying "Am I not an apostle; have I not seen Jesus?" In Galatians, he claims to have been taught by Jesus just as were the other apostles.

We must understand that inspiration of Scriptures does not mean every thing said in the Scriptures is true, but that everything said in the Scriptures was actually said. It was not true, for example, that Jesus would never be killed on the cross. But it is true that Peter said it in Matthew 16:23, in response to which Jesus called Peter Satan.

Peter also got out before God on the Mt. of Transfiguration offering plans to build three altars. God had to tell Peter to shut up and listen to Jesus. Even Paul had to rebuke Peter in Galatians 2:11-14.

Peter was a great man and a pillar of the church, but it is not he who is inerrant; it is the Scriptures themselves.

After the day that Peter led the other 10 apostles to cast lots for Judas' replacement, no one ever hears from Matthias again. We know nothing of him. Paul, on the other hand, who was clearly God's choice as an apostle became the central figure in the propagation of the gospel especially to the Gentiles. He wrote more than half the book in the New Testament, He took the gospel on at least three missionary trips throughout their world, he was stoned, drowned, beaten, imprisoned, starved, hated, loved. He raised (through God's power) a young man who fell to his death in a church meeting. In short, Paul made full proof of his apostleship.

Matthias must have been an honorable man, but he was not (in my opinion) God's choice for Judas' replacement. I believe when we get to heaven and walk around the walls of the New Jerusalem, we will see the names of the 12 Apostles of the Lamb. One of those stones will bear the name of Paul, Apostle to the Gentiles.

Comment: *no one ever hears from Matthias again* - As opposed to most of the other Twelve ?

Comment: The lot is cast into the lap, but the whole disposing of it is of the LORD. Proverbs 16:33. It's hard to argue that God didn't get His way with Matthias based off of this axiom from the Proverbs. Especially in something so crucial as replacing a member of the apostleship.

Answer (score 0):

**Whose name is written on the twelfth foundation stone? Is it Judas Iscariot Or Matthias or Paul?**

The scriptures nowhere refers to Paul as one of the twelve, therefore it is reasonable to say that **Matthias name is written on the twelfth foundation stone.** On the inauguration of the New Covenant with his followers on the day of the Pentecost , Jesus instructed his disciples to wait in Jerusalem for the promised holy spirit,  this means that at the start of the Christian congregation, it was Matthias  who was present and received the promised holy spirit, neither Judas nor Paul were present.

Answer (score -1):

God had chosen Matthias first and then Paul the apostle... Paul claimed he is an apostles and sent to the gentiles... After replacement never seen Matthias .. claim he is an apostles .. so my opinion most probably the apostle Paul...